A Song from The Desert Song (1953?)
Long ago I saw a movie version of the The Desert Song operetta. I think it was probably The Desert Song (1953).
And I remember the Riffs singing as they rode through the desert.  And in the original and most movie versions there should be a song called the Riff Song" with these lyrics:

Over the ground
There comes a sound
It is the drum, drum, drum of hoof-beats in the sand.
Quiver with fear
If you are near
It is the thunder of the "Shadow" and his band.
And all who plunder learn to understand, to understand:
The cry of
Ho!
So we sing as we are riding
Ho!
It's a time you best be hiding Low,
It means the Riffs are abroad,
Go,
Before you've bitten the sword.
Ho!
That's the sound that comes to warn you.
So!
In the night or early morning, you know,
If you're the "Red Shadow's" foe,
The Riffs will strike with a blow,
That brings you woe.
Ho!
So we sing as we are riding
Ho!
It's a time you best be hiding Low,
It means the Riffs are abroad,
Go,
Before you've bitten the sword.
Ho!
That's the sound that comes to warn you.
So!
In the night or early morning, you know,
If you're the "Red Shadow's" foe,
The Riffs will strike with a blow,
That brings you woe.

https://www.google.com/search?q=Teh+riff+song+from+the+desert+song&oq=Teh+riff+song+from+the+desert+song&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOTIJCAEQLhgNGIAEMg0IAhAAGIYDGIAEGIoFMg0IAxAAGIYDGIAEGIoFMg0IBBAAGIYDGIAEGIoFMgoIBRAAGIAEGKIEMgoIBhAAGIAEGKIEMgoIBxAAGIAEGKIEMgoICBAAGIAEGKIE0gEIOTE0MmoxajeoAgCwAgA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#wptab=si:ACC90nxRWvuwqTR4TiacZ7sCfkHhcGgWdDOv2v2HxpHAAuIhwd0hqVQcoOD2_2OWmYVP1pilVYADDps-IFz8aGQrweXcpniWVMoKMtBeYPws6xiyza0NBTd_hzyNaQ1O0aiExukxuGfTtpsgv8FsdCXcTkpe2Aq9206qYmjlGYbUa_AFhgrzw1I%3D
But I remember one line sung by the Riffs as they rode which is not in those lyrics:
"There should (or must) be a place in the sun for everyone."
And since the film was set in the desert I always thought they should have sung someting like: "A pace in the shade for everyone".
And as I remember there were a couple of words at the beginning of that line which I didn't hear clearly but remember as sounding sort of like "Oh my" or "Sidi Omar" or something.  Neighter of those guesses seem to make much sense.
So can anyone tell me about that song's lyrics?

I think we're going to need some concrete evidence for what is currently your (subjective) memory of an interpretation, which may or may not be correct (but I do not agree with the general closure reason here, so VTC as requiring details).

TL;DR:
Specific to the 1953 movie production, the lyrics were nearly entirely rewritten, which is why they bear little resemblance to other versions heard that use the original lyrics.
As explained below it was mainly to avoid royalties going to the original authors.
IMDB info:

The Desert Song and the Cold War: The original refrain for The Riff Song includes the lines: "Ho!/That's the sound that comes to warn you/So!/In the night or early morn, you know/If you're The Red Shadow's foe/The Riffs will strike with a blow/That brings you woe!" In this remake, filmed in the early Fifties at the height of the Cold War and McCarthyism, the "Red Shadow" sounded uncomfortably like the Soviet and Chinese communists, so the lyrics were changed to "If you're El Khobar's foe".


Practically all of the lyrics for "The Riff Song" have been rewritten, even the words that did not have to be changed. This was common practice in several Broadway musical adaptations made before 1955; it was done frequently in the Nelson Eddy- Jeanette MacDonald operettas and it was done in the 1954 film version of "The Student Prince". Movie studios did this so that royalties from all sales of sheet music for the film versions would go to the studios that made the films, not to the original lyricists. Exceptions included the 1936 film version of "Show Boat" and all of the songs except "Cotton Blossom" in the 1951 "Show Boat", as well as the 1943 film version of "Girl Crazy".

https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0045680/trivia/?item=tr0718113
As such, the credits for the movie version of The Riff Song goes uncredited, with new lyrics written by uncredited persons.
(identical notes:)
https://www.derekwinnert.com/the-desert-song-1953-gordon-macrae-kathryn-grayson-steve-cochran-raymond-massey-classic-movie-review-5739/
Most sources for The Riff Song use the original lyrics (as the OP has found) and none use the re-written 1953 movie version.
